# MYSQL: Return a predefined value if result of join is null

Tags: mysql, join, null, default-value, lateral-join

Before all, sorry my very bad english level.
Here's my problem.

If i have two tables:
'Products'

```
|id | product |
|---|---------|
|1  | "Fork"  |
|2  | "Spoon" |
|3  | "Knife" |
```

and 'taxes'

```
|id | id_prod |   tax   |
|---|---------|---------|
|1  |    1    |   21    |
|2  |    2    |   11,5  |
```

If i execute the following command:

```
SELECT product.*, taxes.tax FROM products LEFT JOIN taxes ON taxes.id_prod = products.id
```

I will obtain this result.

```
|id | product |   tax   |
|---|---------|---------|
|1  |  "Fork" |   21    |
|2  | "Spoon" |   11,5  |
|3  | "Knife" |   NULL  |
```

My question is: How i can give a default value when the product is not included in tax?

I want to receive a result like this:
If the default value is "21"

```
|id | product |   tax   |
|---|---------|---------|
|1  |  "Fork" |   21    |
|2  | "Spoon" |   11,5  |
|3  | "Knife" |   21    |
```

How i can do that?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product.*, IFNULL(taxes.tax,21) AS tax
FROM products
LEFT JOIN taxes ON taxes.id_prod = products.id;
```